# Cloning SharePoint (WSS 3.0) and Hyper-V

Tags: sharepoint, hyper-v, virtual-machines, clone

I have a VM with SharePoint (WSS 3.0) installed on it. What is the best way to clone the VM so that the cloned machine has a new SID etc? Running NewSid on the VM breaks SharePoint. Is it possible this way round, or do I have to install SharePoint, but not run the config, and then somehow script the setting up of SharePoint?

Answer (score 3):

If you've already run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard then the SharePoint is effectively tied to that machine. But up to that point you are able to clone it. You can then script the rest.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913832/how-to-duplicate-a-virtual-pc-with-sharepoint-k2-and-domain-controller/928816) on Stack Overflow (should be moved here) for more info.

Comment: Nice find, it looks like this does the trick.  http://www.sharepointblogs.com/nrdev/archive/2008/07/15/tip-how-to-rename-a-sharepoint-server-machine-name.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since its a Hyper-V machine, turn off the SharePoint server VM, rightclick and export. Pick the folder you will actually be running the new VM from, ie. C:\Virtual Machines\ or what not.

Then go to Import Virtual Machine, and in the next dialog you should see some options. One of them is to "copy the virtual machine" which will create a new unique ID for the VM. No need to click the last checkbox since you already have new files (vhd etc) to run the VM from by exporting.

There might be easier options if you have SCVMM installed, but that VM is currently turned off here so I can't check it. But my first approach should only take you a couple minutes.

Comment: Reading the question again, I might have misunderstood it a little bit, but I hope my answer helped either way. Not sure what this will do to the actual SharePoint installation though.